# Cannot resolve keyword 'is_active' into field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Trying to make a password reset view. I'm using the auth_views built in views ie PasswordResetView and PasswordResetConfirmView for resetting password. However I was getting this error

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'is_active' into field. Choices are: active, admin, email, first_name, id, last_login, last_name, logentry, password, staff, timetables
```

. Tried changing `active` to `is_active` and getting this error.

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (active) specified for User
```

Not able to make migrations

models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_first_name(self):
        if self.first_name:
            return self.first_name
        return self.email

    def get_last_name(self):
        return self.last_name

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.is_active
```

forms.py

```
class UserAdminChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for updating users. Includes all the fields on
    the user, but replaces the password field with admin's
    password hash display field.
    """
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name',
                  'password', 'active', 'admin')

    def clean_password(self):
        # Regardless of what the user provides, return the initial value.
        # This is done here, rather than on the field, because the
        # field does not have access to the initial value
        return self.initial["password"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)` to `active = models.BooleanField(default=True)` in your User class, and `is_active` property

see below

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active
```

Comment: Probably the problem is with DB Cache. Try the following.
1. Drop you database, or create a new one,
2. Delete your last migration,
3. Make migrations again.

Comment: @Abedy As I see the problem is that there are two property called the same `is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)` and `@property def is_active(self):`. My solution will fix it.